# ¿Por qué no me salen decimales? (C++)

Tags: c++, double

Realizando un código en C++, al emplear el `cout` para mostrar por pantalla una serie de números "double" me salen como enteros (o sea, si es un 6, querría que saliese 6.00). Ya he probado con el `setprecision`, pero sigue sin funcionarme. Os dejo un ejemplo de código:

```
cout << setw(7) << " h" << ivb[i]-n+1 << " = " << setprecision(2) << b[i];
```

(`ivb` es entero, pero `b` es double).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar utilizando ***fixed***, indicando que habrá un número fijo de dígitos decimales después de la coma.

```
cout << setw(7) << " h" << ivb[i]-n+1 << " = " << setprecision(2) << fixed << b[i];
```

Por ejemplo:

```
cout << setprecision (2) << fixed << 2.1;
```

Imprimiría: **2.10**

De igual forma, el uso de **setprecision** depende de la manera en la que el punto decimal es formateado: fixed, scientific o floatfmt() (por defecto).

Answer (score 1):

No veo problema, pero verifica que el valor de `b[i]` sea double!, seguramente ese es el inconveniente. Por otro lado, ¿qué te parece si se aumenta el número de decimales?, por ejemplo:

```
   << setprecision(5) << b[i];
```

---

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double num1 = 3.12345678;
    double num  = 3;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << num1 << std::endl;;
    std::cout << num1 << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << num << std::endl;;
    std::cout << num << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[ideone](http://ideone.com/axzN4M)</kbd>

Puede ver que aunque num sea double no muestra los decimales quizas esto es lo que le esta pasando, cuanado digo que *sea double!*, por otro lado puede ver que sin usar `<< std::setprecision(5)` le muestra los decimales.

```
std::cout << num1 << std::endl; //3.12346
```

Si quiere que se muestren en un caso similar al de num puede usar:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << num << std::endl;
std::cout << num << std::endl;
```

<kbd>[ideone](http://ideone.com/J6ebd5)</kbd>